# Jquery to disable textarea field not working - Load function

Tags: jquery, long-text-area

I have a textarea which i'm trying to disable using the below code via JQuery read function

```
jQuery( document ).ready( function(){
  jQuery( 'input[id$=oprm12]' ).prop('disabled', true);   //Works for text field
  jQuery( 'input[id$=oprprob]' ).prop('disabled', true);  //Does not works for text area
}
```

The function works for text field but not for textarea field. Any inputs on how to fix this please?

Comment: The reason this wasn't working for you in all cases is because you were using invalid markup. `disabled` is the name of an attribute, not a property as you've got it written. The value of `true` is also not correct per the spec. `'disabled'` is correct. http://stackoverflow.com/a/6961821/1947121

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try with this

```
jQuery('input[id$=oprm12], textarea').attr('disabled','disabled');
jQuery('input[id$=oprprob], textarea').attr('disabled','disabled');
```

Above code make all the text area to disabled

-- 
So javascript solution

```
document.getElementById('{!$Component.oprm12}').disabled = 'disabled';
document.getElementById('{!$Component.oprprob}').disabled = 'disabled';
```

Tested with above code working for me

Comment: Thanks Ratan, tried but still doesnt work during the load event

Comment: are you using apex:inputfield or apex:inputTextarea ? pls add you code

Comment: @PrabhuSethupathy check my updated ans. Use `.attr('disabled','disabled');`

Comment: Thanks it worked now. Shud i use .attr when handling the textareas? I see .prop('disabled', true) working for textfields but not for textareas?

Comment: looks like you have specify `$('input[id$=txtArea], textarea').prop('disabled','disabled');`  textarea then only it is working

Comment: just realised that this command disables all the textarea inpouts fields and not the one very specific with the id

Comment: @PrabhuSethupathy Thanks for notice.  use javascript `document.getElementById('{!$Component.oprm12}').disabled = 'disabled';`

Comment: neither it worked....but wont JQ do the trick? it is not working only during the function load event and very specific for text areas....

Comment: Just now tested in my org it is working with javascript

Comment: Can the code be used in jQuery( document ).ready( function(){  }

Comment: Yes I am using in my org inside  $(document).ready(function() {});

Comment: is the element u are using a textarea in the sobj? well it works for text fields but not for textareas only in the event of ready function

Comment: Yes using apex:inputTextarea with object's textarea field

Comment: well not sure whats going wrong here but the code is not working for me....

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/32663/discussion-between-ratan-and-prabhu-sethupathy).

Comment: create new page and just your field and jq. test there it is working or not